# Word or phrase referring to people who talk with unnecessary styles/gestures

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I can't explain this perfectly, but what do you call a girl/boy who talks with unnecessary style, childish whim, and extra gestures (like small kids sometimes do to attract people's attention).

Answer (score 11):

If these gestures are exaggerated, I'd suggest "flamboyant"; if staged, then "affected."

[affected](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/affected):

> - assumed artificially; unnatural; feigned:
>     *affected sophistication; an affected British accent.*

[flamboyant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/flamboyant%20?s=t):

> - florid; ornate; elaborately styled:
>     *flamboyant speeches.*

(dictionary.reference.com)

Comment: +1 for affected, to describe artificial/deliberately adopted mannerisms solely for the purpose of attracting attention

Comment: I wish I could explain this better, there's a single word for that in my language but I cant explain that well in English. The behavior is "staged" and mostly to attract others' attention.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps animated is the word you are after.

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/animated):

> animated

1. endowed with life or the qualities of life :  alive
2. full of movement and activity < an animated crowd >
3. full of vigor and spirit :  lively < an animated discussion >

Comment: do you mean an animated boy or girl?

Comment: I wouldd say something like "He/she was animated during our discussion regarding foo yesterday.". Don't think I like the sound of "He/she is an animated boy/girl."

Comment: how about attention seeker?

Comment: Not necessarily interchangeable. What if I gesticulate a lot or modulate my voice a lot to emphasise something in a fervent discussion? That might justify my actions without having to be associated with the negative connotations of attention-seeking.

Comment: I wish I could explain this better, there's a single word for that in my language but I cant explain that well in English. The behavior is "staged" and mostly to attract others' attention.

Answer (score 5):

A literal alternative could be **[gesticulator](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gesticulate#gesticulate__2)**

> **gesticulate**: Use gestures, especially dramatic ones, instead of speaking or to emphasize one’s words
>
> *He describes the fascinating journey along the evolutionary path that ‘converted us **from wild gesticulators to smooth talkers**.’*

(Oxford)

Comment: How does it convey the childish manner of gesticulating or childish whim? I am acquainted with some people who gesticulate and speak loudly because of their temperament but they are not like kids in terms of their behaviour.

Comment: Italians are gesticulators because they are full of emotions and this is their nature. But we would not compare them with kids. :)

Comment: @Amande: Fair point. But I think (or rather, hope) that the 'childish whim' part isn't terribly important to the OP. Using gestures is.

Comment: +1..It reminds me of "mudra"...(n ritual hand movement in Hindu religious dancing-TFD) Type of: gesture.to express a thought or feeling. :)-

Comment: @Mysti: Thanks. You don't have to translate `mudra` for me, you know. I'm Hindu. (Not much of a dancer, though!)

Comment: :)-..not for you. (invoked the sanctity of citing quotations)

Comment: @Amande: I think the OP was just trying to paint a picture where someone is using some sort of frantic gestures (in this case, the kid).

Comment: I wish I could explain this better, there's a single word for that in my language but I cant explain that well in English. The behavior is "staged" and mostly to attract others' attention.

Answer (score 1):

**[Compulsive talker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compulsive_talking):** sb who talks in a continuos manner to seek attention
**[Prattler](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prattler?s=ts):** sb who talks in a childish manner

Answer (score -1):

How about [attention seeker](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDoQFjAF&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FAttention_seeking&ei=DnWbVcLRNsS00ATY4ISQDQ&usg=AFQjCNFOg7c7vPLcVysAeq9m-JxXYZdSdg&bvm=bv.96952980,d.dGo). It fits your description.

> ***Attention seeking*** is behaving in a way which is in pursuit of attention from others. Where such behaviour is *excessive and
>   inappropriate*, the term is often *used pejoratively in respect of
>   children's behaviour* in front of peers, or negative domestic
>   interactions.

Comment: I wish I could explain this better, there's a single word for that in my language but I cant explain that well in English. The behavior is "staged" and mostly to attract others' attention.